# How to make a dynamic keyword in Clojure?

Tags: json, clojure

I've got some JSON that looks like this:

`{"_gallery123abc": "foo" }`

But it may also appear like this:

`{"_gallery789xyz": "foo" }`

Is there a way in Clojure to create a keyword to accept a regex so that I can get the "_gallery" value regardless of the ending characters?  Something along the lines of `((keyword #"^_gallery") data)` where `data` is my JSON?

I need it to work in a chain so that I can traverse the structure like: `(-> data :response :nodes :_gallery :slides :title)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it is sensible to make some utility function for that:

```
(defn key-like [m k]
  (let [s (name k)]
    (some #(when (clojure.string/starts-with? (name (key %)) s)
             (val %))
          m)))
```

and then you can use it almost the way you wanted:

```
user> (-> {:a {:b {:_gallery123 {:d "BOOM!"}}}}
          :a
          :b
          (key-like :_gallery)
          :d)
;;=> "BOOM!"
```

another way is to make some function instead of `->` (like `get-in`), which would be capable of retrieving keys depending on the passed type.

```
(defn find-key [m k]
  (if (instance? java.util.regex.Pattern k)
    (some #(when (re-matches k (name (key %)))
             (val %))
          m)
    (get m k)))


(defn get-in+ [m & ks]
  (reduce (fn [curr-val k]
            (if (nil? curr-val) (reduced nil)
                (find-key curr-val k)))
          m ks))

user> (get-in+ {:a {:b {:_gallery123asd {:d "BOOM!"}}}}
               :a
               :b
               #"_gallery\d{3}\w{3}"
               :d)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get a value by a key which matches a regex:

```
for(var key in data) {
     if(/^_gallery/.test(key))
    ... do something with obj[key]
 }
```

Comment: I need it to work in a chain so that I can traverse the structure like: `(-> data :response :nodes :_gallery :slides :title)`

Comment: It wasn't part of the question, however to me you can traverse to nodes by just using data.response.nodes, what are you trying to so?

Comment: You're right.  That wasn't clear so I added it in.  I have found another way to get things done with zippers, but I'm asking because I'm curious if there's another way.